# itextsharp editor for creating tags

Tags: c#, itext

I would like to know if exist some program for editing itextsharp code.

Now I am writting code directly in VS lile:

```
// Delivery address details
int left_margin = 40;
int top_margin = 720;
writeText(cb, "Delivery address", left_margin, top_margin, f_cb, 10);
writeText(cb, drHead["delCustomerName"].ToString(), left_margin, top_margin-12, f_cn, 10);
writeText(cb, drHead["delAddress1"].ToString(), left_margin, top_margin-24, f_cn, 10);
writeText(cb, drHead["delAddress2"].ToString(), left_margin, top_margin-36, f_cn, 10);
writeText(cb, drHead["delAddress3"].ToString(), left_margin, top_margin-48, f_cn, 10);
writeText(cb, drHead["delZipcode"].ToString(), left_margin, top_margin-60, f_cn, 10);
writeText(cb, drHead["delCity"].ToString() + ", " + drHead["delCountry"].ToString(), left_margin+65, top_margin-60, f_cn, 10);
```

But I would like to use some editor for this because this is horrible to write by hand. I am searching for an editor but I can not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you inherited some code, right? I say that because `writeText()` is not from iTextSharp, it is someone's specific implementation that wraps around iTextSharp's code.

iTextSharp is a library that ultimately produces PDFs and as such is bound by the PDF specification. This is first and foremost the most important thing to understand. Even if you already know this you must always keep this top of mind.

iText runs in two basic modes, 1) full abstraction where you add "paragraphs" and "tables" and 2) manual placement mode where you say "write this text using this font at this coordinate and don't worry, I've measured everything so I know where to insert line breaks so it doesn't look weird."

Full abstraction mode (my terminology, not their's) uses the `Document` object and you create new `Paragraph` objects and `Add` them to the `Document` and iText figures the rest out for you. There's less control but if you can live in this mode your live will be so much easier.

Manual placement mode (once again, my terminology, not their's) uses instances of the `PdfWriter` and `PdfContentByte` classes to issue commands that are much closer to the PDF spec. Usage of this mode kind of assumes that you've at least partially read the spec. For instance, you'll should be aware that "paragraphs" and "tables" don't actually exist in a PDF.

The variable that you are using, `cb`, is almost definitely an instance of a `PdfContentByte` so you are using manual placement mode.

Now to answer your question.

No, there are no GUI programs to edit code that's specific to iTextSharp. However, there are programs such as Adobe Acrobat, Adobe Illustrator and Adobe InDesign that do know how to work with PDFs. There are probably free ones out there, too. You can use these programs, find the x,y coordinates of things and manually write those into your code.

Comment: I like the terminology ;-)

Comment: @Chris thx for informations. So the best is to use Adobe and check x,y coordinates and put it into code.

Comment: If you want to design things then yes, I would suggest using a design-based program. The only other option is what you're probably doing now, trying some numbers and see how they look. You'll need to be very conscious of the origin of coordinates, not only the corner but also where they are relative from, page edge, page margin, etc.